# Sharepoint Online - Image Position in RichTextEditor

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, css, html

I have a custom site with a list of posts (something like a blog, but not the standard sharepoint blog), and I'm having an issue with the RichText Editor and images.

The issue consists in inserting an image in the field, and setting the position to the left, so the text occupies the "full" right side of the image. I'm using the default EditForm for the list.

When I use IE (10/11), it formats correctly, but when I use Chrome (33) it does not work. I've checked the differences between both in the markup, and I found the following:

### Final Markup

IE

```
<div class="ExternalClass31AFBE7E6A1048A9BF03F203170FC960"><p><img src="/path/to/image/ImagensWordpress/178B-ana-paula-lisboa.jpg" alt="" style="margin&#58;5px;width&#58;300px;height&#58;300px;vertical-align&#58;auto;float&#58;left;" /></p><p>BIG TEXT HERE</p>
```

CHROME

```
<div class="ExternalClass31AFBE7E6A1048A9BF03F203170FC960"><p><img src="/path/to/image/ImagensWordpress/178B-ana-paula-lisboa.jpg" alt="" style="margin&#58;5px;width&#58;300px;height&#58;300px;vertical-align&#58;baseline;" /><p>BIG TEXT HERE</p>
```

Looking for the issue more deeply, I found that, in chrome, when you set the image to float left, it inserts an empty "class" attribute to the image, looks like a bug.

### Additional Info

1) The site is using Sharepoint Online 2013

2) I've isolated the customizations (using default masterpage, no other customizations on the site)

3) The site have Publishing Feature activated

4) I didn't find this issue using a default website using Blog Template (and no Publishing Feature activated)

5) I tried debugging the JS called to format the image, but hadn't any success, and as it is online based, I don't have too much to work here.

Can someone please give me some directions to investigate further? Thanks in advance!